# Session-timeout configuration doesn't work?

Tags: java, servlets, session-timeout

In `web.xml` I have this

```
 <session-config>
   <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
 </session-config>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>myapplication.SessionListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

In the `SessionListener.java` I have

```
public void sessionDestroyed (HttpSessionEvent event){    
   System.out.println("Visitor Removed!!");
}
```

But it seems `System.out.println("Visitor Removed!!")` has never been executed. I am new to Tomcat 6 and JSP. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can have at least 3 causes:

1. The session has never been created. Listen on `sessionCreated()` as well.
2. You are a bit impatient. Session destroy happens lazily and at intervals. It does not happen *immediately*. If you fire a *new* request in the same session while it has been expired, then `sessionDestroyed()` will be called. Or if you have a bit more patience, the server will run its low-prio timer job to reap all expired sessions.
3. You are not using the `myapplication.SessionListener` class in the classpath as you think you're using, maybe the one actually in the classpath doesn't have a sysout line.

Comment: or 4. System.out does not output to where you think it does

Comment: Check the tomcat log under $TOMCAT_HOME/logs in either catalina.<date>.log or localhost.<date>.log

Comment: Thank you BalusC. It should be Cause 2: I was not patient.